# reading the elements of 2nd page after submit click

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I am working on a web form fill using excel cells data, and the issue here is that after filling the text in the first page using the elements ID, when it click on Submit it loads a new IE.

Now here I am not able to fill the text using the elements ID etc, as its (VBA) not identifying it or not considering it.

IE Page loads properly here no issue.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://xyzfrmTarget=New&Text_ident=002719&frmOption=CREATE"
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    Set doc = IE.document
    'IE.document.getElementById().Value="test"
    'doc.getElementById("ui-new_widget-1_new_company_12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value
    doc.getElementById("ui-new_widget-1_monitor_12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value
    doc.getElementById("new_date").Value = "2019-01-19"
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("c2").Value
    doc.getElementById("new_no_mail").Click
    IE.document.forms(0).submit
End Sub
```

It submit the 1st page with the Text data from excel, but issue with the 2nd page which loads

Comment: I've tried to fix your formatting issues for your syntax but you may want to give it a once over to make sure it is what you intended

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper waits after navigate and `.click` and work off `.document`. This should update with new content after the `.click`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PerformActions()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://xyzfrmTarget=New&Text_ident=002719&frmOption=CREATE"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("ui-new_widget-1_monitor_12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value
        .document.getElementById("new_date").Value = "2019-01-19"
        .document.getElementById("new_no_mail").Click

         While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

         '.document ''< do whatever references off .document here
         'other code
         '.quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr, i was working to get the links working for long time...kept the things aside for some new approach..i will come back to this....thanks

Comment: happy days then :-)